# Drawing rectangle underneath PIXI.Text

Tags: pixi.js

In a word game I am trying to draw score as white numbers above a blue (or red) rectangle:

[image: screenshot]

For example, in the above screenshot it is the number "13".

Here is my entire class `Score.js` (with currently hardcoded `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`):

```
"use strict";

function Score(color) {
        PIXI.Container.call(this);

        this.interactive = false;
        this.buttonMode = false;
        this.visible = false;

        this.bgGraphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
        this.bgGraphics.beginFill(color, 1);
        this.bgGraphics.drawRect(0, 0, Score.WIDTH, Score.HEIGHT);
        this.bgGraphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(this.bgGraphics);

        this.text = new PIXI.Text('XXX', {font: '20px Arial', fill: 0xFFFFFF});
        this.text.x = 1;
        this.text.y = 1;
        this.addChild(this.text);
}

Score.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Container.prototype);
Score.prototype.constructor = Score;

Score.WIDTH  = 36;
Score.HEIGHT = 24;

Score.prototype.setText = function(str) {
        this.text.text = str;
}
```

I wonder, how to modify my `setText()` function, so that a new rectangle is drawn on each call - as a bounding rectangle for the `str` argument?

I have looked at the [PIXI.Text.getBounds()](https://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.Text.html#getBounds) method, but it returns a `Matrix` and not a `Rectangle`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `this.text.width`.  This has historically had some [bugs associated with it](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/197), but it should be working right in the latest version.